# How do I compare char literal to any array index without declaring array index inside []

Tags: java

I have this condition:

```
   if(Character.isLetter(com[0]) && com [0] != '*' ){
         System.out.println("Valid");
     }
```

What I want to happen, is to compare this literal '*' to com[0] dynamically without declaring the inside of com as zero.

Example input when I type this g*g it still displays valid the only time it will go invalid is when I type *gg. I'd like to display the invalid no matter where I put the * char not just the 1st index.

I'm creating a program to check whether a variable is valid or invalid so any special characters are not allowed except this _ (under score)

Here's the full code:

```
public class identifier {
public static void main (String args[]){
  char[] com = new char[26];

int flag = 0, i = 0;
    System.out.println("Enter an identifier");
      Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
     com = sc.next().toCharArray();



    if(com[i] != 0 && Character.isLetter(com[i]) && com[i] != '*') {
         System.out.println("Valid");         
     }



    else {
         System.out.println("Invalid");
    }      

     while((int)com[i]==0)
     {
          if(!Character.isLetter(com.toString().charAt(i))&& !Character.isDigit(com.toString().charAt(i)) ){
          flag=0;
          break;
          }
          i++;
     }
     if(flag==1){
         System.out.println("Valid");
     }
}
```

}

Comment: do you mean something like `int i = 0; if(Character.isLetter(com[i]) && com[i] != '*' )`?

Comment: Like with a `for` loop?!

Comment: @Eran still produces the valid output

Comment: Provide a [mcve] ... your requirement is not clear. In the question it looks like you only want to validate the first character in the array, the title mention _any index_. [edit] the question to be more specific please!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Can you explain why you expect "g*g" to be valid or invalid as the case may be, and why "*gg" should be valid or invalid? Do you know that `com[0]` means the first character? Are you trying to check every character in the word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is (I assume):

```
String comm = new String(com);
if (!comm.isEmpty() && Character.isLetter(comm.charAt(0)) && !comm.contains("*")) {
```

This means: if the string of `com` starts with a letter and it does not contain '*' ...

Comment: You need to build the `String` with `new String(com)` first since `com[0]` let you know it is an `char[]` so you can't simply do `com[0]` and also use `String.contains` or `String.isEmpty` ...

Comment: the problem is, I'm using char datatype @Joop Eggen any suggestions? or should I use toString?

Comment: @AxelH I indeed forgot that - who ever works with `char[]`? Corrected

Comment: @ehelpfit String is more powerful, especially with internationalisation: (1) for a letter sometimes two chars are needed, as Unicode goes above into the three byte range, and char is UTF-16, two bytes. (2) `"Scheiße".toUpperCase(Locale.GERMAN)` is `"SCHEISSE"`.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException ooo, so right, I had it mixed up. Corrected again.

Comment: I see majority of you suggested to use String then I'll go for it thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Define an `int` with the index you want. It´s better to use `String`. This way you will use three methods.

> `isEmpty()`: Returns true if, and only if, length() is 0.
>
> `charAt(int index)`: Returns the char value at the specified index.
>
> `contains(CharSequence s)`: Returns true if and only if this string contains the specified sequence of char values.

```
int i = 0;
if(!com.isEmpty() && Character.isLetter(com.charAt(i)) && !com.contains('*') ){
     System.out.println("Valid");
}
else{
     System.out.println("Invalid");
}
```

For more info about the methods, check the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html).

**UPDATE:**

Since you explained that you want to check that if `*` was contained in any index, then I changed my solution to meet your requirements.

Comment: Salem
That's what I did, initialize variable i to zero

Comment: Why are you comparing `com[0] != "*"` ? If you check that it is a letter then, it will be true that is not `*`

Comment: char arrays don't have a `contains` method.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException You are right, was thinking in a String solution and didn´t change the com[i] to charAt(i).Thanks!

Comment: I tried the code but it goes for else condition instead

Comment: @ehelpfit could you provide your input? I defined a `String com = "gg";` and prints `Valid`. Instead with `"g*g"` it shows nothing (you should define what the `else` behavior)

Answer (score -1):

```
int i = 0;
if(Character.isLetter(com[i]) && com [i] != '*' ){
     System.out.println("Valid");
 }
```

Just declare zero inside a variable and reqrite com[0] as com[i]

Comment: Still checks the 1st index